# How can I edit lines in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This my pandas dataframe:

```
C:\BlokusDuo-master\app\src\main\java\blokusgame\mi\android\hazi\blokus\GameLogic\Block.java                 
C:\BlokusDuo-master\app\src\main\java\blokusgame\mi\android\hazi\blokus\GameLogic\BlockFactory.java          
C:\BlokusDuo-master\app\src\main\java\blokusgame\mi\android\hazi\blokus\GameLogic\Map.java                    
C:\BlokusDuo-master\app\src\main\java\blokusgame\mi\android\hazi\blokus\GameLogic\Player.java                 
C:\BlokusDuo-master\app\src\main\java\blokusgame\mi\android\hazi\blokus\GameLogic\PlayerAlgorithm.java        
C:\BlokusDuo-master\app\src\main\java\blokusgame\mi\android\hazi\blokus\GameLogic\PlayerConstants.java
```

I need to extract the string after  the sixth '\' delimiter and replace each '\' in the rest by .

```
Output exemple for the first line:
blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Block.java
```

If I use split it will be complicated!

Comment: Simplest method I can think of is `rsplit` on the slash and `'.'.join` the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution using `str.extract` and `replace`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[r'C:\BlokusDuo-master\app\src\main\java\blokusgame\mi\android\hazi\blokus\GameLogic\Block.java',
                        r'C:\BlokusDuo-master\app\src\main\java\blokusgame\mi\android\hazi\blokus\GameLogic\BlockFactory.java',
                        r'C:\BlokusDuo-master\app\src\main\java\blokusgame\mi\android\hazi\blokus\GameLogic\Map.java',
                        r'C:\BlokusDuo-master\app\src\main\java\blokusgame\mi\android\hazi\blokus\GameLogic\Player.java',
                        r'C:\BlokusDuo-master\app\src\main\java\blokusgame\mi\android\hazi\blokus\GameLogic\PlayerAlgorithm.java',
                        r'C:\BlokusDuo-master\app\src\main\java\blokusgame\mi\android\hazi\blokus\GameLogic\PlayerConstants.java']})

df['y'] = df['x'].str.extract(r'^.*\\java\\(.*)$')
df['y'].replace(r'\\', r'.', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

yields

```
blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Block.java
blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.BlockFactory.java
blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Map.java
blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Player.java
blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.PlayerAlgorithm.java
blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.PlayerConstants.java
```

Rather than look for the Nth slash, you can use regular expressions to find the key 'break' in your text string (in this case, `\java\`) and extract everything after that. Then you can just replace `\` with `.`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
import re

s = r"C:\BlokusDuo-master\app\src\main\java\blokusgame\mi\android\hazi\blokus\GameLogic\Block.java"

def replace_sixth(s):
    iterator = re.finditer("\\\\",s)
    location = [ next(iterator) for _ in range(6) ][-1]
    start = location.start()+1
    return s[start:].replace("\\",".")
```

And then you apply to your dataframe: `df.apply(replace_sixth)`

Answer (score 0):

Two things about pandas you need to know to do this.

1st: 
str operations on a dataframe column (or pandas series) allow for anything you can do with a string
e.g. `df.columnname.str.replace()` or `df.columnname.str.capitalize()` etc..

2nd is indexing:
When you split you will have a list inside and you want the 6th item over you use

```
str[<index_here>]
```

or

```
str[<start>:<end>]
```

If you know these two things you can do it in one short line.

```
df['fixed_filenames'] = df.files_column.str.split("\\").str[6:].str.join('.')
```